# Do flex container properties never apply to the children of flex containers in them?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I set the flex-direction value of .main-header the children of .main-nav are in a row not a column. So I was wondering if the children of flex-containers that are in flex-containers never get affected by the flex-container declarations of the parent container of their parent container.

```
 <header class="main-header">
    <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Best City Guide</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">ice cream</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">donuts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">tea</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">coffee</a></li>
    </ul> 
</header><!--/.main-header--> 


@media (min-width: 769px) {.main-header,.main-nav { display: flex;}  
                           .main-header { flex-direction: column; align-items: center;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

flex-direction will only apply to the children of .main-header, not to any other descendants. If you add flex-direction to: .main-header, .main-nav { display: flex;} instead, then it will apply to the children of both .main-header and .main-nav.

Comment: ok thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media (max-width: 969px) {

.main-header,.main-nav {     display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;} 


}
```

```html
     <header class="main-header">
        <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Best City Guide</a></h1>
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">ice cream</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">donuts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">coffee</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </header><!--/.main-header-->
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not an inherited property so it won't pass down to children. You can check to see if a property is inherited through some sites like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) or [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp).

If you want the child flex-container's children to align in column, you have to specifically set it again.

Answer (score -1):

You can inherit it by flex-direction: inherit;